# Android: how to make a GroupBox widget?

Tags: android, groupbox

It appears that Android doesn't offer such a useful widget. However, my screen design requires a view like this:

[image: Design example]

Also, the interaction design requires that such boxes are displayed and hidden, depending on other data.

Of course, I could construct such box from separate elements in my XML layout (e.g. from a shape and a textview over it), but then managing their visibility turns into hell...

So it's clear that what is needed here is a container, like a relative layout. Such container can have children in XML layout and can be shown and hidden with a simple setVisibility(...) call.

Can someone give me a tip how to do that, please?

Comment: Your link results in a 503 error.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is one, but I hacked together soemthing manual...not the same I know, but thought I'd share "@drawable/divider" is a 2 pixel square grey image. Creates the illusiuon of a box around the controls.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linLayout02">
            <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <ImageView
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:background="@drawable/divider"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow1"  android:visibility="gone">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/image_folder" android:minWidth="100px" android:visibility="gone"></TextView>
                <EditText android:text="..." android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/txtImageFolder" android:enabled="false" android:visibility="gone"></EditText>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow2">
                <LinearLayout
                  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="left">
                    <ImageView
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:background="@drawable/divider"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                    <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/cbDisplayText" android:text="@string/text_below_images"></CheckBox>
                    <LinearLayout
                      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="right">
                        <ImageView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:background="@drawable/divider"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow3" >
                <LinearLayout
                  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="left">
                    <ImageView
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:background="@drawable/divider"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvLocale" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/locale" android:minWidth="100px"></TextView>
                    <Spinner android:id="@+id/cboLocales" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:minWidth="100px"></Spinner>
                    <LinearLayout
                      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="right">
                        <ImageView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:background="@drawable/divider"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow3_1" >
                <LinearLayout
                  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="left">
                    <ImageView
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:background="@drawable/divider"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvPitch" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/pitch" android:minWidth="100px"></TextView>
                    <SeekBar android:minWidth="100px"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/barPitch" android:max="200" ></SeekBar>
                    <LinearLayout
                      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="right">
                        <ImageView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:background="@drawable/divider"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow3_2" >
                <LinearLayout
                  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="left">
                    <ImageView
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:background="@drawable/divider"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvLocale" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/speed" android:minWidth="100px"></TextView>
                    <SeekBar android:minWidth="100px" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/barSpeed" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:max="200"></SeekBar>
                    <LinearLayout
                      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="right">
                        <ImageView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:background="@drawable/divider"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/tableRow4" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <LinearLayout
                  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="left">
                    <ImageView
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:background="@drawable/divider"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                    <Button android:minWidth="100px" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:id="@+id/btnSave" android:text="@string/save"></Button>
                    <Button android:minWidth="100px" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:id="@+id/btnCancel" android:text="@string/cancel"></Button>
                    <LinearLayout
                      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="right">
                        <ImageView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:background="@drawable/divider"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <ImageView
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:background="@drawable/divider"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingTop="2px">
                <ImageView
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:background="@drawable/divider"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <LinearLayout
                  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="left">
                    <ImageView
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:background="@drawable/divider"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                    <TextView android:text="@string/download_msg" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
                    <LinearLayout
                      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="right">
                        <ImageView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:background="@drawable/divider"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <LinearLayout
                  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="left">
                    <ImageView
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:background="@drawable/divider"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                    <TextView android:text="Step 1: Download and Install eSpeak:" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
                    <Button android:minWidth="80px" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btneSpeak" android:text="@string/eSpeak"></Button>
                    <ProgressBar android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/barESpeak" android:visibility="gone"></ProgressBar>
                    <LinearLayout
                      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="right">
                        <ImageView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:background="@drawable/divider"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <LinearLayout
                  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="left">
                    <ImageView
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:background="@drawable/divider"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                    <TextView android:text="Step 2: Download and Install Languages:" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
                    <Button android:minWidth="80px" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btnLanguages" android:text="@string/languages"></Button>
                    <ProgressBar android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/barLanguages" android:visibility="gone"></ProgressBar>
                    <LinearLayout
                      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="right">
                        <ImageView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:background="@drawable/divider"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <LinearLayout
                  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="left">
                    <ImageView
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:background="@drawable/divider"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                    <TextView android:text="Step 3: Reboot the device:" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
                    <Button android:minWidth="80px" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btnReboot" android:text="Reboot"></Button>
                    <LinearLayout
                      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="right">
                        <ImageView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:background="@drawable/divider"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <LinearLayout
                  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="left">
                    <ImageView
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:background="@drawable/divider"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                    <TextView android:text="Note: If Text to speech still fails repeat Step 2 and reboot again." android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
                    <LinearLayout
                      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="right">
                        <ImageView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:background="@drawable/divider"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <ImageView
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:background="@drawable/divider"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp" />
            </TableRow>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

for others who have the same problem, you can use this library:

https://github.com/homayoonahmadi/GroupBoxLayout

It doesn't use any white or other color backgrounds for hiding border under the label

Answer (score 0):

Keep this in your Drawable file name "selector_fieldset_background.xml"

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <stroke
      android:width="1dip"
      android:color="#4fa5d5" />
</shape>
```

And this in you layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_fieldset_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
  </LinearLayout>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:text="Order Information"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This will create a Group box Component as shown in your image.