# How to create a typical C# GroupBox widget in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, groupbox

I was looking for a code that simulates the typical GroupBox of C# because it doesn't exists on Eclipse. My intentions are to create a layout in which has to be a "GroupBox" inside where also has to be more information.

An approximately example could be graphically explained in the image below:

[image]

Hope you can help me.

Comment: See this link, I hope this will help you

[Create a TextBox in Android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977566/android-how-to-make-a-groupbox-widget

Comment: I have found the solution in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251332/make-a-frame-inside-a-linear-layout